# XGBoost `.predict()` without label or target column?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, training-data, inference

I am trying to use XGBoost to predict on a dataset where the test dataset does not have labels. How can I make it so that the xgboost model does not fail when a target column is not provided?

```
# TRAIN_DATA looks similar to TEST_DATA except TEST_DATA does not have a `target` column

import xgboost as xgb
# read in data
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(TRAIN_DATA, label=TRAIN_DATA.target)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(TEST_DATA)
# specify parameters via map
param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }
num_round = 2
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
# make prediction
preds = bst.predict(dtest)
```

Output:

```
                raise ValueError(msg.format(self.feature_names,
>                                           data.feature_names))
E               ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['geohash', 'uupm', 'driver_supply', 'requested_at', 'target'] ['geohash', 'uupm', 'driver_supply', 'requested_at']
E               expected target in input data

../venvs/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:1541: ValueError
```

Comment: your feature names should not include `target` column when you train

Comment: Why? As long as I specify `label=target` it shouldn't use the target column

Comment: You have 'target' in your training dataset (as @Narendra_Prasath said) - this is your problem

Comment: No, consider using your model in the real world. You won't have access to the labels, but you still want to generate predictions (do inference)

Comment: This tutorial explains how to remove 'target' from your training dataset: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/xgboost-in-python

Comment: @information_interchange yes you will not have access to the target variables for interference in the real world. But that doesn't mean that you have to train `target` column in your training data.

Comment: I understand that I don't _need_ `target` in the train data. But, whether I include it or not doesn't affect the training process, or the predictions I get. So if I have it in the train data, then I don't see why it is an issue in the `predict` call.

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong, I will re-verify in the morning. But if you look at the [data file](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/data/agaricus.txt.train) then you see that the labels are included

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

Select all column except `target` column as follows

```
TRAIN_DATA[TRAIN_DATA.columns.difference(['target'])]
```

you can change in your code for training your features:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(TRAIN_DATA[TRAIN_DATA.columns.difference(['target'])], label=TRAIN_DATA.target)
```

Ideally, for training you should not expose your `target` column for feature.

You can do inference without any issue at all.

Comment: It doesn't cause data leakage, check out the source data used in the tutorial: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/data/agaricus.txt.train

Comment: @information_interchange `dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(TRAIN_DATA, label=TRAIN_DATA.target)` is an very clear self-contained example of data leakage. The target variable is not a feature, so it must be excluded. As the above answer correctly states, use `dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(TRAIN_DATA[TRAIN_DATA.columns.difference(['target'])], label=TRAIN_DATA.target)` instead.